# How to avoid error-message during the execution of a bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, file

I need to write a bash-script which will find all files with name string.h on the computer and copy them to some folder. My code is here:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo find / -type f -name "string.h" -exec cp {} $HOME/MyDocuments \;
```

But during the execution of the script, I get error-messages on my console terminal "permission denied". How I can avoid getting this message? Console terminal must be clear.

Answer (score 2):

Suppress the error messages from `stderr(2)` to the `NULL` stream designated by `/dev/null`

```
sudo find / -type f -name "string.h" -exec cp "{}" $HOME/MyDocuments \; 2 > /dev/null
```

where the `2` in the above line stands for file descriptor.

---

I would personally recommend you to investigate the **actual cause** of the issue rather than suppressing it. Do the above only if you are **absolutely** sure that the errors are trivial.